# Bootstrap carousel not importing

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I have been trying to implement [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-extended-320-compatible) bootstrap carousel snippet, however it doesn't work properly for me. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heba0/1md08dy1/) for my attempt. 
ps: I tried to import another carousel but it showed the behavior.

Here is the js associated with the snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 5000
        });

        $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

        //Handles the carousel thumbnails
       $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
            var id = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
        });


        // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                 var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
                $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the external resources for Bootstrap.  See updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cttrxkf6/1/

```
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried doing the same changes to my jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/heba0/1md08dy1/2/)  but it is still not working. Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: Yes, in the left pane there's a link called external resources.  You need to add bootstrap js and css links there.  Cheers!